# How many ordered pairs $(x, y)$ of positive integers satisfy $x^2−2y^2=1$, where $y$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How many ordered pairs $(x, y)$ of positive integers satisfy the
> equation
> $$x^2 − 2y^2 = 1$$
> where $y$ is a prime number?
>
> (A) $0\;$ (B) $1\;$ (C) $2\;$ (D) $4$

I am getting a ordered pair $(3,2)$ directly as start from smallest prime no. to put in place of $y$. But by putting checking infinite prime numbers not possible.

Can somebody suggest any good method??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I suggest looking for more solutions.  Shouldn't take you long to notice a useful (and easily proven) pattern.

Comment: ok @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $y$ is odd, then $x^2-2y^2\equiv 2$ or $3$, not $1\pmod4$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  can you elaborate little more I didn't get it

Comment: This is a Pell's equation , so any pell solver with an additional constraint of $y$ as prime will work.

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma:**  Modulo $4$, $a^2\equiv0$ if $a$ is even, and $a^2\equiv1$ if $a$ is odd.

**Proof:**  $(2k)^2=4k^2$, and $(2k+1)^2=4(k^2+k)+1.$  QED.

---

If $y$ is any prime besides $2$, then $y$ is odd, so $y^2\equiv1\pmod4$, so $2y^2\equiv2\pmod4$.

Also by the lemma $x^2\equiv0$ or $1\pmod4$.

Therefore, modulo $4$,  $x^2-2y^2\equiv0-2$ or $1-2$, which is $2$ or $3$, respectively, so $x^2-2y^2\neq1$.

Therefore, the only possible solution to $x^2-2y^2=1$ where $y$ is prime has $y=2$.

Comment: Nice way! $~~~~~~$

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume  $x=2m+1$ where  $m$ is a positive integer. Then, we get $(2m+1)^2=2y^2+1$. Simplification of the above equation will lead to
$$2m(m+1)=y^2$$
Note that  $m$
and  $m+1$
are two consecutive integers so at least one of them is even. Thus  $y$
is even. But  $y$
is prime. Hence we find that  $y=2$. Thus, we get  $m=1$
from the last equation and the value of $y$ that give us $x=3$. Thus, there is only one pair, namely $(x,y)=(3,2)$.

**Alternative proof**.

Let be $x^2-2y^2=1 \implies x^2=2y^2+1$ is odd. Hence $x=2a+1$. From
$x^2-2y^2=1$ we have

$$(2a+1)^2=2y^2+1$$ i.e. $2a^2+2a=y^2$, $y$ is even i.e. $y=2$. From $x^2-2y^2=1$ with $y=2$ we get $x=3$.

Comment: I like the alternative proof. This is a multiple choice and does not need to overkill it anymore!